# How to calculate array size for a binary search tree with a certain height?

Tags: arrays, height, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am working on binary search tree implementation using array. I need to create an array for a BST with a specific height. How do I calculate that size?

Comment: simple googling provides a lot of material on relation bet. a BST's height and no. of nodes. Algo and even code for achieving the BST-in-array thing is available easily. Please look them up and then come back again. we can discuss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you are talking about implementation with  indexation like in a binary heap.

All vertices stored in array. First element of this array - root. If some vertex of BST is i-th element of array, it's left son stored in cell with index 2*i, right son  - in cell with index 2*i+1. The scheme of such representation in memory is shown below:

[image]

You are asking about tree size for some given height. Height - is a number of levels in a tree. In other words, height is a length of the path from root to any leaf. In the picture above BST has height  = 2.

How calulate size of array for storing tree with fixed height? It's just sum of geometrical progression. Level with height = 0 has 1 element, next level with height=1 has 2 elements, next level has 4 elements and so on. Level with height = H has 2^H elements.

**Array size for storing tree with height = H** is size enough for storing all levels from 0 to H: 

2^0 // cells for level with height=0

+
2^1 // cells for level with height=1

+...
+2^H = **2^(H+1)-1**;

Important note - many programming languages has zero-based array indexation. So, when you declare array like `int tree[2^(H+1)-1]` it means that elements numbered from 0 to 2^(H+1)-2 while you want them be numbered from 1 to 2^(H+1)-1. Element with index 0 is not convenient - it breaks "parent i,left son 2*i" rule because 0=2*0. In other words when I say first element in array is a root I mean tree[1], not tree[0]. Just ignore tree[0].

Finally, **required_array_size for BST with height H** = calculated_size + zero_ignoring_shift = 2^(H+1)-1 +1 = **2^(H+1)**

Comment: If `i` - node than `2i+1` and `2i+2` its children.

Comment: I guess, it's for avoiding "0*2=0" problem? It's really not so importnant. As for me, it's more convenient to work with 1-based indices.